# Creating a dictionary by iterating a data frame in pandas row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is one simple `dataframe`.

```
sample=pd.DataFrame({'Budjet_id':['K1','K2','K3'],'cost':[20000,30000,4000]})
sample 
   Budjet_id    cost
0       K1     20000
1       K2     30000
2       K3     4000
```

Convert this into dictionary and embed this in another dictionary like this.

```
 data={}
 data['work'] = 'Budget'
 data['data_sample']=[{m:sample.values[i][n] for n, m in enumerate(sample.columns)} for i in range(0,len(sample))]
 data
```

This gives the following output.

```
{'work': 'Budget',
 'data_sample': [{'Budjet_id': 'K1', 'cost': 20000},
                 {'Budjet_id': 'K2', 'cost': 30000},
                 {'Budjet_id': 'K3', 'cost': 4000}]}
```

But the expected output is the following.

```
{'work': 'Budget','data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K1','cost':'20000'},
               'data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K2','cost':'30000'},
                'data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K2','cost':'4000'}}
```

Is there a way to reach this?

Comment: problem of expected output is there is duplicated `key`s, dict in python need unique keys. So cannot create.

Comment: it looks like your desired result needs a dictionary where the key `data_sample` appears more than once. Dictionaries don't permit that.

Comment: `@jezrael`,`@BoarGules`,`@MircoT` Yes, All your comments are acceptable. I am trying to replicate this code in R `for(i in start_from_row:NROW(dataset)){ data_sample_row = list()     data_sample_row[['data_sample']] = as.list(dataset[i,]) `by creating a simple `data frame` and add some other `items` in the `for loop`. then send that as `JSON script` to `requests.post`

Answer (score 1):

```
{'work': 'Budget','data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K1','cost':'20000'},
           'data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K2','cost':'30000'},
            'data_sample':{'Budjet_id':'K2','cost':'4000'}}
```

If this is the output that you want it is not a valid dictionary because you have multiple data for the same key.